# Python mock return default value after initial predefined values returned

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-mock

I'm mocking a message queue, where I want it to return 2 messages and then return None each time it is called (to simulate that the message queue is now empty). However, after the 3rd message call I get an error from mocking framework saying that there is no "next" value.

Here's an example:

```
from mock import MagicMock

mock_message_queue = MagicMock(name='message_queue')
expected_messages = ['message 1', 'message 2', None]
mock_message_queue.fetch.side_effect = expected_messages

print('mock_message_queue.fetch() = {}'.format(mock_message_queue.fetch()))
print('mock_message_queue.fetch() = {}'.format(mock_message_queue.fetch()))
print('mock_message_queue.fetch() = {}'.format(mock_message_queue.fetch()))
print('mock_message_queue.fetch() = {}'.format(mock_message_queue.fetch()))
```

Output:

```
mock_message_queue.fetch() = message 1
mock_message_queue.fetch() = message 2
mock_message_queue.fetch() = None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/wsi/.PyCharm2017.1/config/scratches/mock_message_bus.py", line 10, in <module>
    print('mock_message_queue.fetch() = {}'.format(mock_message_queue.fetch()))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1062, in __call__
    return _mock_self._mock_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1121, in _mock_call
    result = next(effect)
StopIteration

Process finished with exit code 1
```

So basically I want it to always return None after it returns 'message 2'. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you need the last element of the list of values to repeat endlessly. You can use `itertools.repeat` for this, along with `itertools.chain` to join it onto the list of actual values.

```
expected_messages = itertools.chain(['message 1', 'message 2'], itertools.repeat(None))
```